# Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ then Prove $\sigma(\pi (\mathbf{R} ))\ =\ \mathbf{B} (\mathbf{R} )$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, borel-sets

I know that the $\sigma$-field generated by the class of all open subsets of $\mathbf{R}$.

I want to show that a field generated by $\pi (\mathbf{R} )$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field ( $\mathbf{B} (\mathbf{R} )$) on $\mathbf{R}$.

i.e. $(\pi (\mathbf{R} ))\  =\  \  \sigma (\pi (\mathbf{R} )$

considering $\pi (\mathbf{R} ))\  =\  \{ (-\infty ,a]\  :\  a\  \varepsilon \  \mathbf{R} )$

I read that I need to show $\mathbf{B} (\mathbf{R} )\  \subseteq \  \sigma (\pi (\mathbf{R} ))$

But I need more insight.

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: The statement in the second line is wrong.